# Dynamic Approach For LCA

Tags: algorithm, tree

I reading a LCA [Tutorial](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor&module=Static)  Where it defines P[1,N][1,logN] where P[i][j] is the 2j-th ancestor of i

[image]

Why it is **using logN** and **why 2j ancestor is used** ? I did not understand it's intuition ?

I could not understand the last step :

```
//we compute LCA(p, q) using the values in P
      for (i = log; i >= 0; i--)
          if (P[p][i] != -1 && P[p][i] != P[q][i])
              p = P[p][i], q = P[q][i];

      return T[p];
```

Comment: Because you can write each number n as the sum of O(log n) powers of two.

Comment: @NiklasB. would you please explain me with a example it will be useful for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `P[i, j] = 2^j-th ancestor of i`, then:

```
P[P[i, j - 1], j - 1]
```

Is the `2^(j - 1)-th` ancestor of the `2^(j - 1)-th` ancestor of `i`. We have:

```
2^(j - 1) + 2^(j - 1) = 2*2^(j - 1) = 2^j
```

So by defining it like that we achieve a couple of important things:

1. **Memory efficiency**: since the matrix is `n x log n`, the memory used is `O(n * log n)`;
2. **Time efficiency**: because we can find each ancestor by using a recurrence that splits the problem roughly in 2 at each step, we have an efficient, logarithmic solution for each query.

Comment: sir, would you explain me the above piece of code in the updated question

Comment: @user4447943 - it moves up the three from `p` and `q` using powers of two. This will make it reach the common ancestor in `O(log tree_height)`.